# When MnO2 acts as a catalyst to speed up the decomposition of H2O2 what does it actually do?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, catalysis, oxides

Everywhere I look it just states that $\ce{MnO2}$ acts as a catalyst but I have yet to find a simple explanation for what it actually does. What is the mechanism involved in simple terms?

Comment: Decomposition of H2O2 is catalyzed by pretty much _everything_.

Comment: It's heterogeneous catalyst - surface chemistry isn't well understood.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131904/what-is-the-rate-expression-for-decomposition-of-ceh2o2-in-the-presence-of